# (How) do I need to account for censored data in LCMM?

Tags: r, mixed-model, panel-data, missing-data, latent-class

I have a large dataset of within-individual repeated measures, where each participant has varying number of observations (multiple rows of data for each participant). Missing data is largeley non-random, as the variable I am trying to model predicts an event that results in an individual leaving the dataset.

I am trying to use LCMM to model latent classes based on the variable, but I am not sure how to account for missing data.

Currently, I have the model written as

```
m <- lcmm(variable ~ time, random = ~ time, subject = 'ID', mixture = ~ time, 
          ng = 2, idiag = TRUE, data = data, link = "linear")
```

Does entering time as a random effect sufficiently account for missing data?

If not, what can I do to account for meaningfully missing data?

Edited to add: It is a large longitudinal data set with repeated measurements of risk variables meant to predict reincarceration. I am basically trying to establish whether latent class analysis is a useful method for describing different patterns of change in risk.

Comment: What is your motivation for using a latent class model ? Please can you edit the question to provide more detail about the data and the study design.

Answer (score 2):

The `lcmm()` function fit a latent class linear mixed-effects model. This postulates that there are some underlying sub-populations in your data that you wish to recover. The model is estimated using maximum likelihood, and therefore it will provide you with correct inferences provides that any missing data in your outcome `variable` are missing at random and that the model is correctly specified.

If you have any background knowledge indicating that the missing data mechanism is more complex, i.e., missing not at random, then you could try fitting a joint latent class model. This is available in the same package via function `Jointlcmm()`.